# How to distribute numbers of one column in four different column proportionately in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, numbers

Please refer attached image
Example: [Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7doge.jpg)

Need to distribute items among A,B,C,D in the proportion of 45:20:30:5 respectively.

Conditions:

1. If the share of A,B,C,D is a fractional number then decimal part need to be ignored. Share can be the whole number only. 
   eg. 2.56 will be 2 and 0.56 will be 0
2. Total count of the share must be exactly equal to 'Total item'.

eg. 5 will be divided as A:2, B:1, C:2, D:0

How can this calculation be performed in excel sheet?

Comment: You can't ignore decimal parts of a fraction and then expect it to add up to the total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your formulas like this:
[image]

Because of rounding errors, the total won't add up to the first column. So to correct for that, in the last column, you can use `=A3-B3-C3-D3`. Or you can use a different column. Either way, someone's getting cheated. ☺

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and single formula, enter in `B2` and drag to right, then down,

```
=ROUND($A2*CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A),45,20,30,5)/100,0)
```

However your approach is wrong. Ignoring the decimals will never total to the column A value (Whatever math you do).